# upload a file in the same page as the form using php and ajax not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

Trying to upload a file using `php/ajax` but seems like its not working, maybe its not recognizing the `$_FILES["file_name"]["tmp_name"]` variable in the `upload_file.php` because I could not display it in the page.

Can you please help!

index.html

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="upload_file.js"></script>

<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file_name" id="file_name" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="RUN" id ="btnSubmit"> 
</form>

<div id='upload_here_div'></div>
```

upload_file.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    console.log(file_name +'uplooad');

    $('#btnSubmit').click(function(e) {

        console.log('click trigger');
        var file_name           = $("#file_name").val();


        $("#upload_here_div").load("upload_file.php?file_name=" + client_info )
        console.log('value for file_name=' + file_name ); //
      });

});
```

upload_file.php

```
<?php
$file_name  = $_REQUEST['file_name'];

if ( isset($_FILES["file_name"])) {

    //if there was an error uploading the file
    if ($_FILES["file_name"]["error"] > 0) {
        echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file_name"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
    else {

          $file_locatioon = "upload/".$file_name ;
          echo 'file_locatioon = '.$file_locatioon."<br>";
          move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file_name"]["tmp_name"], $file_locatioon);
          echo "ploaded!!<br>";
    }

 } else {echo "No file selected <br />";}
?>
```

Comment: Where are you sending the file? I see a `.load` call but that is not a post request, let alone a `multitype/form-data`

Comment: you're using `['file_name']` and `["file"]` and the input bears `name="file_name" id="file_name"` - Consult the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php and check for errors http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: @Halcyon, Thank you for the feedback! what you mean with  let alone a `multitype/form-data` ?

Comment: @Fred-ii- sorry, that was just a typo in my behalf. I'm using `file_name` in all the files. corrected!

Comment: Your `upload_file.php` is set up to receive a `multipart/form-data` request but you seem to be sending it a plain GET request. How are you sending the file?

Comment: I doubt that you can use `$file_name  = $_REQUEST['file_name'];` as a filename. More like `$file_name = $_FILES["file_name"]["name"];` as per the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php and make sure the folder is writeable. Sidenote: I only know serverside. JS stuff, is out of my scope.

Comment: @Halcyon I removed `multipart/form-data` from enctype and changed POST to GET for the form method, and the file still not uploaded to the `upload` folder

Comment: ^ no don't do that ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ files work with POST not GET and an enctype is required.

Comment: @Fred-ii-  the folder is writeable and changing `$_REQUEST['file_name']` to `$_FILES["file_name"]["name"]` didn't change the output. thank you so much for looking into this questions!

Comment: @Fred-ii- :/ I did change it back and now I get the message `No file selected ` maybe $_FILES["file_name"]["name"] is not being used properly?

Comment: You're welcome. It's hard to say. Like I said earlier, I don't know JS enough to help out any further, I work server-side for the most part. TBH, when someone asks me to install something like that, I just find a script out there that works from demos lol I just modify the PHP to my liking afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this [tutorial](http://abandon.ie/notebook/simple-file-uploads-using-jquery-ajax) before and tested OK. By using `FormData` may give what you want.
But please take the browser compatibility in consider. For more information please reference [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData).

Answer (score 1):

I think you get a same problem with this [jQuery Ajax File Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload). 
Maybe it is helpful for you.